# CSS Select:disabled not working

Tags: css

I have next function:

```
changeStateSelect() {
    if ($('#idAsignaturaGlobal').prop('checked')) {
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('required', false);
    } else {
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('required', true);
    }
}
```

and next CSS:

```
.form-horizontal select:disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

But it is not working. I tryed it adding it into the function with .css but neither... I do not understand why it happening this... Why could it be?. Thank you.

EDIT: This is my HTML code (Is React JS + Bootstrap)

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal text-center" method="GET" action="">
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="idAsignatura" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 label-select2">Asignatura: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <select name="nAsignatura" id="idAsignatura" class="js-states form-control select2" required></select>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="nAsignaturaGlobal" id="idAsignaturaGlobal" onChange={this.changeStateSelect} value="true"/>
                    <label for="idAsignaturaGlobal">
                        Incidencia con la asignatura
                    </label>
                </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if disabled is true or false.  If the attribute is there at all, it's disabled.

Comment: The problem is that never shows red color neither pointer. It is as if disabled not exist

Comment: I have tried to put prop disabled into other select (which no have changeStatus) and neither shows css

Comment: You'll need to publish your HTML too to tell if your selector is correct or not.

Comment: post your markup please so we have a [mcve] of your current problem

Comment: I'm assuming this is your markup? Seems like it's working for me. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbMRxd

Comment: I added the HTML. I think my markup is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I added your actual problem

Your problem is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nAsignaturaGlobal" id="idAsignaturaGlobal" onChange={this.changeStateSelect} value="true"/>
```

You have `onChange` when it should be `onchange="changeStateSelect()"`

### Demo

```js
function changeStateSelect() {
    if ($('#idAsignaturaGlobal').prop('checked')) {
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('required', false);
    } else {
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#idAsignatura').prop('required', true);
    }
}
```

```css
.form-horizontal select:disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal text-center" method="GET" action="">
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="idAsignatura" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 label-select2">Asignatura: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <select name="nAsignatura" id="idAsignatura" class="js-states form-control select2" required></select>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="nAsignaturaGlobal" id="idAsignaturaGlobal" onChange="changeStateSelect()" value="true"/>
                    <label for="idAsignaturaGlobal">
                        Incidencia con la asignatura
                    </label>
                </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that my select no changes of color (not shows red color, is if it does not accept CSS, as if the markup were wrong). Thank you.

Comment: @JuMoGar sorry I didn't realize. I added a new demo addressing your problem. You had `onChange`, instead of `onchange`. Check the demo to see it work.

Comment: @JuMoGar you also have `onchange="this.changeStateSelect"` which I changed to `onchange="changeStateSelect()"`

Comment: Yeah, Sorry. I have copied it bad. In ReactJS onchange = onChange, if not, you get an error and do not work. And '()' were removed too. My Select seems disabled, that is working, as in your example, but it do not apply my styles, applies default styles.

Comment: @JuMoGar I'm having a hard time understanding. I added ReactJS and changed it to onChange, and as you can see in the edited demo, it works. In what ways is yours different from the demo right now, and why doesn't the code I have in the demo work for you?

Comment: I do not know what is happening... Your code and mine are the same. The only difference is that I remove the '()' because with them it does not work for me. As I tell you, I correctly disable the Select, but it does not apply my custom styles (red color, nor cursor). So I'm already thinking that I have conflict with another CSS directive that I have in my file .. There is no other.

Comment: Hi. I have an idea why I might not go. Maybe because I'm using the Select2 plugin?